# Suggest linking of content types

Tags: 7, organic-groups

I have two OG groups - Organizations and E-hoods. and group content types - goals and ideas. I would like users to have a suggest feature which enables people to basically link groups and group content. Also the linking should be moderated.

Is there a module that does this ? or if anyone can give me a direction to work on, I can work on it too. I'm using Drupal 7 and have a limited knowledge on drupal.

Thanks!

Comment: A 29% acceptance rate may not yield you many useful answers.  Have you read [ask] - it lays out some useful StackExchange etiquette.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at [References](http://drupal.org/project/references) for the linking part, and also [Workbench](http://drupal.org/project/workbench) for the moderation part, and lastly [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) to give users access to do the linking.

- Create a Node reference field on one content type, to link the child node to the parent (or vice-versa)
- Use Field Permissions to grant everyone access to enter/edit the field
- Use Workbench to force changes into a new revision which need to be approved.

Comment: Is there a way where I can use the OG group audience field without using the references module ?

Comment: Yes, I would just give it a try.  There are a lot of details that are unknown, so I would give it a try like you said and see if you can't use Field Permissions and Workbench to simply control access and moderation.